# Attach posts based on category and position

Tags: database, hooks

I'm working with some old data that hasn't been attached correctly, visibly it makes sense and all posts are in order but in the database there is no reference of any post connection. There are thousands of posts here, so I'll just show an example of what I'm working with, and what I would like to achieve via an action hook, or function. Or even just an update_post method.

Example list of posts currently

```
Post Title 1 (Category = Folder)
Post Title 2 (Category = Item)
Post Title 3 (Category = Item)
Post Title 4 (Category = Item)
Post Title 5 (Category = Item)
Post Title 6 (Category = Folder)
Post Title 7 (Category = Item)
Post Title 8 (Category = Item)
Post Title 9 (Category = Item)
Post Title 10 (Category = Item)
```

What I would like to achieve is:

Any posts in category 'item' that are below a post in category 'folder' to then become children of the above Folder post, so my posts would become something like this:

```
Post Title 1 (Category = Folder)
- Post Title 2 (Category = Item Post_parent = Post Title 1)
- Post Title 3 (Category = Item Post_parent = Post Title 1)
- Post Title 4 (Category = Item Post_parent = Post Title 1)
- Post Title 5 (Category = Item Post_parent = Post Title 1)

Post Title 6 (In category: Folder)
- Post Title 7 (Category = Item Post_parent = Post Title 6)
- Post Title 8 (Category = Item Post_parent = Post Title 6)
- Post Title 9 (Category = Item Post_parent = Post Title 6)
- Post Title 10 (Category = Item Post_parent = Post Title 6)
```

I'm wondering if someone can just put me on the right track of how I could do this writing a script myself. Something along the lines of:

For each post in category link > that is below a post in category folder > make this post a child of post in folder category above

What I am struggling to reference is the 'that is a below a post'. Could this be referenced by using published post date?

Comment: OK, what exactly is the question? If you're looking for somebody to write you a script, you should be asking at freelancer sites.

Comment: @janh hi, no not looking for someone to write a script, just looking for a brief description of what methods I could take to achieve my desired output

Comment: @janh I've updated my question to be a little clearer!

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if you're actually looking at post revisions. Keep in mind that Wordpress creates a revision of a post any time you make a change to it. Each revision stays in the database, however, the way you access it is by going into the post itself and then locating the revision section in the upper right hand corner.

The posts you see might actually not be "orphaned" posts.

I would also recommend you consider doing some Wordpress maintenance to clean out older post revisions. I would recommend you [look into using WP-Optimize](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-optimize/) for this (be sure to read the documentation).  See if that actually addresses your issue.

Comment: Hi Bearly. Thanks for this. No, it's definitely not a case mistaken view or anything like that. I'm looking directly the at how the posts are listed in the main posts admin screen, and have gone into the database also. I'm wondering if there is a way I can run some type of script, like > for each post in category link > that is below a post in category folder > make this post a child of post in folder category above